# Importing metadata-extractor library not working in Processing

Tags: import, metadata, processing

I am trying to extract the EXIF data from images in Processing by importing the metadata-extractor library by drewnoakes.com. I have tried the two possible methods to import a library but it still doesn't work at all.

What I've did:

1) Drag and drop the JAR file into my sketch and used the import statement import com.drew.*; but it is still complaining that the library doesn't exist.

2) Placed the JAR file in the Processing folder in My Documents folder and import library using the "Import Library..." option but when I select the library, no import statement is added automatically like the other libraries behave except for a blank line is inserted.

What do I have to do in order to import this library into the sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .jar must be in the `libraries` subdirectory of your `processing` folder, not the processing folder itself. Make sure that the directory structure matches this (replace 'theLibrary' with your library name):

```
 Documents
       Processing
             your sketch folders
             libraries
                   theLibrary
                         examples
                         library
                               theLibrary.jar
                         reference
                         src
```

You may be able to omit the `examples`, `reference`, and `src` directories, but it would be safer to just make empty folders. Taken from the [online help](http://wiki.processing.org/w/How_to_Install_a_Contributed_Library), which has more instructions if you are still stuck.

Edit: I installed it myself, here is the exact step sequence I took:

- Downloaded `metadata-extractor-2.6.4.zip` from the website you posted
- went to my sketchbook, went to libraries, created a folder called `metadata_extractor` with a subfolder called `library`
- extracted `metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar` and `xmpcore.jar` to my `library` folder
- renamed `metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar` to `metadata_extractor.jar`
- opened Processing, went to sketch > import library and it was listed there

Comment: I have re-organised the folders to the one you have mentioned but the problem still persists. It is still giving a blank line instead of the import statement.

Comment: Did you restart the processing editor afterwards? Did you follow the instructions on that page?

Comment: Yes. I did restart Processing. I even renamed the JAR file to "metadata" as the original name contains special characters. I have also tried the import statement `import.metadata.*;` and `import.com.drew.*;` but the problem still persists.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the steps I used that correctly installed it on my computer, I hope that helps.

Comment: It worked. I didn't know that I needed the xmpcore.jar as well. Thank you very much!